# How to convert dimension into measure in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I created a calculated field using IF...THEN...END condition and now I'd like to convert the dimension into a measure (sum).

I'd expect such option in the context menu (right-click) but even when I  select that field in a sheet as a measure, it seems still to act as a dimension.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something you need to have as a dimension for your entire flow, just right-click on Epic field and select Convert to Dimension.

Doing so, you'll have that calculated field listed among your original dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

right clict and select "discrete" will turn that into measure. Also, you can drag and drop that column to "Marks" area such as color.

Comment: Whether a field is displayed as discrete or continuous is a completely separate topic from whether it is treated as a dimension or measure. Two different things. Not to come across as harsh -- Tableau documentation hasn't always done a great job of clarifying this distinction. But it is important for understanding how to use Tableau well.